# My code fails with error messages json_line = json.loads(line) and cert_check(TOPCERTPATH, TOPCSVPATH)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a python script that is supposed to take some input and produce output as an csv file. Any help would be greatly appreciated! This code is supposed to read processed Censys X.509 cert data and JSON results of VirusTotal queries. Then it is supposed to take the outputs CSV of Issuer common name, subject domain name, and true or false regarding whether any positive results were found for the domain on VT.

I commented out the try and pass statements as @Joel recommended. Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/reporter1.py", line 126, in <module>
    cert_check(TOPCERTPATH, TOPCSVPATH)
  File "C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/reporter1.py", line 112, in cert_check
    json_line = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

import csv
import json
import pprint
import sys


TOPCERTPATH = 'TopScoringCERTS.txt'
BOTTOMCERTPATH = 'BottomScoringCERTS.txt'
TOPCSVPATH = 'TopScoringResults.csv'
BOTTOMCSVPATH = 'BottomScoringResults.csv'
VTOUTPUTPATH = './output/'
VTOUTPUTEXT = '.txt'


pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


# Check files from VirusTotal queries for any positive results
# Result is false unless any nonzero positive result is true
def vt_result_check(vt_result_path):
    vt_result = None
    #try:
    vt_result = False
    with open(vt_result_path) as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

            # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
            #try:
            for sample in (vt_data['detected_referrer_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
           # except:
              #  pass

            # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
            #try:
            for sample in (vt_data['detected_communicating_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            #except:
               # pass

            # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
            #try:
            for sample in (vt_data['detected_downloaded_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            #except:
                #pass

            # Look for any positive detected URLs
            #try:
            for sample in (vt_data['detected_urls']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            #except:
               # pass

            # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
            #try:
            if (vt_data['Dr.Web category'] == "known infection source"):
                    vt_result = True
            #except:
                #pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
            #try:
            if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "elevated exposure"):
                    vt_result = True
            #except:
                #pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
            #try:
            if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "phishing and other frauds"):
                    vt_result = True
            #except:
               # pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
            #try:
            if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "suspicious content"):
                    vt_result = True
            #except:
                #pass

            #pp.pprint(vt_data)
    #except:
        #pass
            return vt_result


# Read the processed Censys data and outputs results for the Issuer and Subject
def cert_check(certpath, csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['issuer', 'subject_dom', 'vt_result']
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['Issuer Common Name', 'Subject Common Name', 'VirusTotal Results'])
        with open(certpath) as certfile:
            for line in certfile:
                issuer_cn = None
                subject_cn = None
                subject_dom = None
                #try:
                json_line = json.loads(line)
                issuer_cn = json_line['parsed']['issuer']['common_name'][0]
                subject_cn = json_line['parsed']['subject']['common_name'][0]
                subject_dom = subject_cn.encode('utf8')
                subject_dom = subject_dom.replace('*.','')
                vt_result_path = VTOUTPUTPATH + subject_dom + VTOUTPUTEXT
                vt_result = vt_result_check(vt_result_path)
                writer.writerow([issuer_cn, subject_dom, vt_result])
                    #pp.pprint(json_line['parsed']['subject']['common_name'][0])
                    #print(issuer_cn, subject_dom,vt_result)
                #except:
                    #pass


cert_check(TOPCERTPATH, TOPCSVPATH)
cert_check(BOTTOMCERTPATH, BOTTOMCSVPATH)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your read every line in the "certpath" like it's a JSON string.  Therefore if you have data in that file that is not JSON compatible you will hit this error.  Can you provide a link to the file you're trying to parse, or a sample of the contents? Also you should select the back trace text and press the code button so it's more readable

Comment: @sehafoc Thank you for your help! Here is the output from the files I'm trying to determine to parse. 
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "verbose_msg": "Domain not found"
}

Answer (score 0):

Well the exception is a JSON decode error so I'm suspecting that you're not parsing the file contents correctly.

Assuming your file content is as so

```
Not json
Not json
Still not json because beginning of line {"valid": "json"}
{ "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" }
```

You can augment your current function to give more data

```
def cert_check(certpath, csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, 'r') as csvfile:
        # fieldnames = ['issuer', 'subject_dom', 'vt_result']
        # writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        # writer.writerow(['Issuer Common Name', 'Subject Common Name', 'VirusTotal Results'])
        with open(certpath) as certfile:
            for line in certfile.readlines():
                try:
                    json_line = json.loads(line)
                    print("line is JSON!", line)
                    pprint(json_line)
                    print("Breaking loop now")
                    break
                except:
                    print("Line is NOT JSON ", line)
                    # print(traceback.format_exc())
            else:
                print("File contains no JSON!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("test_data", "w") as test_file:
        test_file.write("Not JSON \n")
        test_file.write("Not JSON \n")
        test_file.write('Not JSON even though there is json later { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" } \n')
        test_file.write('{ "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" }')

    cert_check("test_data", "test_data")
```

Outputs

```
Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON 

Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON 

Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON even though there is json later { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" } 

line is JSON! { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" }
{'response_code': 0, 'verbose_msg': 'Domain not found'}
Breaking loop now
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ultimately, how do I fix this script though? I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Only the person who wanted you to write this program can tell you how it's supposed to behave. If you have clear requirements but don't understand how exactly to implement them, please [edit] the question to clarify this. You certainly cannot use a JSON parser on input which isn't JSON; but we can't know what you should be doing instead.

Comment: @bedford, Replace your cert_check with the one above.  find which line that you think should be parsed as JSON, update the question with the data.  question should be something like in this file (example of file contents) I'm trying to parse this line (enter example of line) as json. and get these fields.  You don't have enough info in the question to answer it.

Comment: @sehafoc Thank you for your response! I did that but all I get is this output:

Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON 

Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON 

Line is NOT JSON  Not JSON even though there is json later { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" } 

line is JSON! { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" }
Line is NOT JSON  { "response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Domain not found" }
File contains no JSON!

Comment: don't replace the whole file just the check_cert function

Comment: @sehafoc I only replaced the check_cert_function, however, it still doesn't work. I still get the same output as last time.